# Boto3 botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3

I am trying to fetch the daily cost of all resource having tag `{'key': 'string', 'Values':['string']}` in a region, for this i am using `boto3 CostExplorer` APIs.

But I am getting an error **botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ce.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/"**

here is code that i am using

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ce')

response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2020-02-01',
        'End': '2020-03-01'
    },
    Metrics=['BlendedCost'],
    Granularity='DAILY',
    Filter={
         'Tags': {'Key': 'string', 'Values': ['string']}
     }
)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Cost Explorer is only available in us-east-1 currently.

Refer to this link for the current list of supported regions: Amazon Cost Explorer Supported Regions [AWS Service Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/billing.html)

[image]

***Resolution:***

You'll need to change the region accordingly in your ***.aws/config***

or set the correct region when creating the client for AWS Cost Explorer as follows :

```
import boto3

ce-client = boto3.client('ce', region_name='us-east-1')
```